# Html Default Select Option - Different Color - Doesn't Work On Current Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to have a select field with a default option, which is not intended as a selection,  be gray/faded out, while the other selectable  options be black. I've tried jquery but it doesn't seem to work on my site, the problem seems to lie with jquery no longer supporting the implemetation. In the jsfiddle link below it works as it should, but only up to 1.72. How do I support/implement this. Thank you for any and all help!

Jquery Implementation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {       
  function colorgray() {
    if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
      else $(this).removeClass("empty");
  }
     $("select.loan-type").change(colorgray);

$("select.loan-type").change();
     $("select.loan").change(colorgray);

$("select.loan").change();
});
```

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1854/)

Comment: $("select.loan-type") hasn't got a dot or hash in front. if it's a class add a dot, or id add a hash. where are you calling the function from ?

Comment: It hasn't got a `.` or a `#` in front of it because it is not a class or an ID. `select` is an element.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't seen the fiddle link and went storming in ....Beddy byes for me then, half asleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class empty is applied, but then it is is removed again when you call 
`$("select.loan").change();` again.

Leaving this line out of your code appears to result in the correct effect.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {       
  function colorgray() {
    if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
    else $(this).removeClass("empty");
  }
  $("select.loan-type").change(colorgray);


  $("select.loan").change(colorgray);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSFiddle that does what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1863/

```
if($("select option:selected").val() == "0")
{
    $(".loan-type").css("color", "gray");  
}

//Change color to black after selecting
$(".loan-type").change(function(){
   $(".loan-type").css("color", "black"); 
});
```